# Google TV template 2 works fine on my browser but not on TV

Tags: google-tv

I'm using template 2 for the Google TV and using AJAX calls. Everything loads perfectly on the browser but when I try to load it on an actual TV that has a google TV device, only the sound loads, but there is no actual video showing up...ANybody has any clues of why this isn't showing up...

I'm using the HTML5 templates btw. thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOOgle TV does not support playing HTML5 videos inside android webView